# Make field mandatory in import

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have one mandatory  field in my entity X, but while importing data, I can create records even if I dont give that mandatory field a value, which is not good.
How could I make that field mandatory even while importing?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

Most mandatory fields are only enforced on the user interface. There are a few exceptions on some system entities, e.g. contact - lastname, account - name, incident - name, to list a few.

You want to enforce mandatory fields at the platform level, e.g. after the user interface before it is entered into the database.

The easiest way to do this is the following:

1. Add a synchronous workflow to your entity, after on create or on change of your field.
2. Add a condition to the workflow, if your field contains no data then run the following step:

   - Stop workflow; canceled, with a message of your choosing.

This will result in the import failing when the field is not populated and the record would not be created or updated. If you were to test this within CRM this would result in an error dialog being shown to the user.

Comment: You should set the workflow or plugin to execute before the record is created. That way you can block the creation of the record. If the check is done afterwards it will just show an error and still create the record

Comment: @StefanWilliam-Worrall; I believe the the changes will be rolled back as part of the failed CRM transaction, so the record should be removed if it was created.

Answer (score 2):

You could create Pre Operation  plugin  which runs on Create ,if entity doesn't contain this field ,throw out an error.(EDIT:I haven't tried this out so I'm not 100% sure it'll work)

**Or**

You could create Post Operation plugin which runs on Create , if entity doesn't contain this field ,then delete target entity.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement level of fields (e.g. Business Required) is not enforced when doing imports (it is mainly enforced through the UI).

You will have to ensure that the required fields are set in your source data before doing an import.

Answer (score 1):

Business rules with scope of "Entity" is the simplest no code solution to enforce this scenario.

> For example, bulk data import, workflows, plugins, API/SDK calls would bypass the CRM forms and therefore would also bypass any JavaScript or form Business Rule validations you might have configured. These type of server-side validation had typically required plugins or synchronous workflows.
>
> Luckily, business rules now have a new scope “Entity” which applies at the server level instead of the form level. What this means is that these business rules, just like plugins and sync workflows, will execute even if you are not using a CRM form in your transaction because they happen on the platform (server side) instead of the form (browser/client side).

Link to learn more: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/gonzaloruiz/archive/2016/08/15/business-rules-vs-sync-workflows-in-crm

Comment: My one liner solution is straight forward with no code solution which are not mentioned in other 3 answers. Link is just to gain extra knowledge if someone (non crm; down voters) bumps & want to search again to know what's  business rule (google lucky direct link) :)